# Moving table row from point A to point B with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On the images you can find page example. Look at the difference between left and right table. Left field is previous iteration, right - current iteration. I need:

(On previous iteration field)

1. Set background color on the position of new row
2. Create new row

After that move new row to the right field with JQuery animation.

First image:

[image: First image]

Second image:

[image: Second image]

```
<div class="control">
    <div class="prev_iter">
        <div class="truthTable">
            <table class="TT"> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="bit" style="border: none"> </th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>2</sub></th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>1</sub></th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>0</sub></th>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="current_iter">
        <div class="truthTable">
            <table class="TT"> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="bit" style="border: none"> </th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>2</sub></th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>1</sub></th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>0</sub></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bit" style="border: none">0: </td>
                    <td class="bit">0</td>
                    <td class="bit">0</td>
                    <td class="bit">0</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div class="controlButtons">    
        <input id="back" name="back" onclick="controllerSwitchSteps(this.id);" type="button" value="&lt;Previous">
        Step <span id="stepNumber">2</span> from <span id="totalSteps">13</span>
        <input id="next" name="next" onclick="controllerSwitchSteps(this.id);" type="button" value="Next&gt;">  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried any `javascript` or `jQuery` yet?

Comment: No, i am not tried because dont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a jQuery solution myself, you'll have to put in some work yourself and work on the animations yourself, but in order to take the last row of one table and put it on another, you should be able to do something like this:

```js
$("tr").on("click", function() {
  $(this).appendTo("#clonedTable");
});
```

```css
td {
border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Click on a row to move it to the other table!</p>

<table id="originalTable">
  <tr>
   <td>Data 1 </td>
   <td>Data 2 </td>
   <td>Data 3 </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Data 4 </td>
   <td>Data 5 </td>
   <td>Data 6 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr />

<table id="clonedTable">
  <tr>
   <td>Data 7</td>
   <td>Data 8</td>
   <td>Data 9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay, apparentl, my answer was not correct. I have found the similar deplacement, but this happens in moment, i want smooth movement.